# Using regular expressions to extract certain text from a string in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I am scraping data from a website and the tag contains the text 'ANSWER (1)'.
My goal is to extract just the '1' from the string using regular expressions in python.

Is there a simple way to go about doing this?

Comment: Please consider searching either this website or google first. This is the most basic form of Regular Expressions! e.g: ``([0-9]+)``.

Comment: Can you please provide some of the input, what kind of tag it is in?

Comment: The string is held within an H3 tag. I have the data extracted and stored into a string. So at this point, my goal would be to take the string and only extract the data in between the parenthesis.

Comment: Not really sure why this is marked as duplicate. This is a regex question, not a beautiful soup question.

Comment: The concept is the. Search this site for "Python Regular Expressions". Please consider posting more specific questions and do your homework.

Comment: It's encouraged to use a parser such as BeautifulSoup, not regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
import re
s = "ANSWER (1)"
print re.search(r".*\((\d)\)",s).group(1)
```

Comment: This did work, thank you. I need to brush up on my knowledge of regular expressions. Thanks for the help